# Using 2 different AnnotationActionEndpointMapping

Tags: spring-ws, wss4j

I´m using Spring WS 2.2.0 with WS-Security (wss4j) and WS-Addressing.

I want to publish two web services, one with username-password authentication and soap body encryption/decryption (request and response) and the other just with username-password authentication.

How should I configure `Wss4jSecurityInterceptor` at `AnnotationActionEndpointMapping`?

I would like to configure two `AnnotationActionEndpointMapping` with different  `Wss4jSecurityInterceptor's` so there would be two different `EndpointInvocationChain`, one with encryption and the other without it. But you can´t specify two different `AnnotationActionEndpointMapping` because it fails when registering endpoints at `AbstractActionEndpointMapping.registerEndpoint()`.

Or should I extend `AnnotationActionEndpointMapping`, redefining `registerEndpoint()` so I can specify whether to register or not.